# No scrolling after minimizing webpage?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have just been setting my webpage to fit all screen sizes and resolutions. However, now when I shrink the window size there is no option to scroll around the page and things cannot be seen. Can anybody help me out please? Below is my code:

index.html:

```
    *<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!--[if IE]>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <![endif]-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
    conditionizr({
        debug: true,
        scriptSrc: 'js/conditionizr/',
        styleSrc: 'css/conditionizr/',
        ieLessThan: { active: true, version: '9', scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        chrome: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        safari: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        opera: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        firefox: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        ie10: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        ie9: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        ie8: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        ie7: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        ie6: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        retina: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        touch: { scripts: true, styles: true, classes: true, customScript: false },
        mac: true,
        win: true,
        x11: true,
        linux: true
    });
    </script>



</head>
<body>
<div id="main" width="100%;">
<div class="intro" style="font-family:Adobe Gothic Std B;"> SetUp2Go.co.uk offer complete set up businesses packs delivered to your door. Allowing you to go out, start earning money and be your own boss.  
We have spoken to industry professionals who have helped us choose <br> quality essential items in setting up your own business. </div>
    <div class="borderHorizontal"> 
        <a href="#" class="homeButton">Home</a>
        <a href="products.html" class="productsButton">Products</a>
        <a href="about.html" class="aboutButton">About</a>
        <a href="faqs.html" class="faqButton">FAQ's</a>
        <a href="contact.html" class="contactButton">Contact Us</a>
        <div class="emailText" style="font-family:Adobe Gothic Std B;"><b>setup2go@hotmail.com</b></div>
        <div class="facebookLink" type="image" src="facebook-icon.png" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/SetUp2Gocouk/893630380654424"></div>

        <form class="paypal" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.co.uk">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
        <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">

    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="borderVertical">
    <img class="logoPhoto" src="images/image.png" alt="logo">
    </div>

    <div class="borderHorizontalNotTrading" style="font-family:Adobe Gothic Std B; text-align:center; color:#FF0000; font-size:38px;">
    <b>Currently not trading check back soon!</b>
    </div>

    <img class="windowCleanPhoto" src="images/WindowCleaningkit.jpg" alt="windowClean">
    <img class="shoeShinePhoto" src="images/shoeShine.jpg" alt="shoeShine">
    <img class="hairdresserPhoto" src="images/mobile_hairdresser.jpg" alt="sandwichMaking">
    <img class="homeCateringPhoto" src="images/home_catering.jpg" alt="placeholder">
    <img class="massuesPhoto" src="images/massues.jpg" alt="placeholder2">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
background: rgba(235,235,235,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(235,235,235,1) 0%, rgba(227,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,1) 24%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(235,235,235,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(227,227,227,1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(214,214,214,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(235,235,235,1) 0%, rgba(227,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,1) 24%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(235,235,235,1) 0%, rgba(227,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,1) 24%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(235,235,235,1) 0%, rgba(227,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,1) 24%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(235,235,235,1) 0%, rgba(227,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,1) 24%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ebebeb', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );

    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: My first guess is that `position:fixed;` is doing it.

Comment: I have tried changing that but then page doesn't fit the screen initially and you can first scroll if you get me? I want the user to not be able to scroll when maximized but then be able to if the window is shrunk

Comment: We can use Media Queries for different screen resolutions ?

Comment: You can use `@media` to write css for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for small resolution.

```
@media all and (max-width: 559px) {
body
{ 
   position:relative;
}
}
```

There are lots of example on web related to media queries.

Comment: Please check this fiddle and try to shrink the browser and you can see the scroll. Re run it after removing the media query and you can see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/4hpzk/

Comment: It isnn't changing in any way? I can't scroll to start with which is good but then when the screen has shrunk I still can't and things are then missing off the screen

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Well!! with the help of above media query I am getting a scroll horizontal and vertical if the browser is shrunked :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58521/discussion-between-aliasgar-rajpiplawala-and-user2177781).